# Want my column display minutes and want it to sum in hours

Tags: development, date-time, field-type

I have an issue  again...

I create list from csvfile. I convert string with date into DateTime type like this:

```
 string[] formattedDates = { "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", "mm:ss", "HH:mm:ss", "dd.MM.yyyy", "HH:mm:ss" };

 newEntry["Duration"] = DateTime.ParseExact("00:05", formattedDates, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

but when i check my list of data -  duration time (ex: 01:44, 00:05) converts and shows up like this 8/27/2012 00:05 (but it is not Time it is only duration time)

So the questions are:

1. How make it show up in the list in suitable format (without date = "00:05")?
2. Will minutes 00:05, 00:41, 01:03  sum as 01:49  - total duration?
3. If 2. is not possible, can you offer your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Marc D Anderson( [link] (http://sympmarc.com/2009/05/29/summing-calculated-columns-in-dvwps/)):

1. call template

   ```
   <td class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">                                              
   <xsl:variable name ="NodesTotals">                             
    <xsl:call-template name="TotalValue">
        <xsl:with-param name="Node" select="$nodeset"/>
    </xsl:call-template>                        
   </xsl:variable> 
       sum : <xsl:value-of select="$NodesTotals" />
   ```
2. Sum rows

   ```
     <xsl:template name="TotalValue">
       <xsl:param name="Node"/>     
       <xsl:param  name="Sum" select="0"/>      
       <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$Node">
            <xsl:variable name="desimal">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string($Node[1]/@Duration),1033,'HH:mm'),':')*60 + substring-after(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string($Node[1]/@Duration),1033,'HH:mm'),':')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:call-template name="TotalValue">
               <xsl:with-param name="Node" select="$Node[position()!=1]"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="Sum" select="$Sum + $desimal"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

         </xsl:when>   
         <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$Sum"/></xsl:otherwise>    
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
   ```

Thank you!